# Which general rebuked the King of England over logistics?

Tags: napoleonic-wars, great-britain, war-of-1812

I have a bit of a hunt for anyone with a fair bit of trivia knowledge about letters.

Back in a business class during my undergraduate studies, a professor shared a letter from a general to the King in which he is responding to a request to account/audit of the supplies the army had. The response was essentially that the general could either win the war or count supplies, which would the King prefer?

I have searched exhaustively without luck. I recall that the war in question was fought with muskets and cannon, and suspect that it may have been from the War of 1812, but am unsure on the specific conflict.

So, which general had the gall to rebuke the King when asked to account for his troops provisioning?

Comment: This might be a quite common trope because there is an occurrence of a similar event in Naples in 1506: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuentas_del_Gran_Capit%C3%A1n

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a famous if apocryphal letter, traditionally attributed to Wellington during the Peninsular War, though I wouldn't be surprised if a variant floating around transposed it to America a generation earlier. It is addressed to the War Office not to the King directly (which would in any case have been very anachronistic for the period) but otherwise seems very likely to be the one you remember.

The bit below is quoted from [this version](https://www.bradford-delong.com/2014/07/hoisted-from-the-archives-from-202-years-ago.html), but searching on key phrases will bring up many others, all more or less the same:

> This brings me to my present purpose, which is to request elucidation of my instructions from His Majesty's Government so that I may better understand why I am dragging an army over these barren plains. I construe that perforce it must be one of two alternative duties, as given below. I shall pursue either one with the best of my ability, but I cannot do both:
>
> 1. To train an army of uniformed British clerks in Spain for the benefit of the accountants and copy-boys in London or perchance,
> 2. To see to it that the forces of Napoleon are driven out of Spain.

However, it is **almost certainly apocryphal**. Poking around on Google Books did not find any hits for key phrases ("train an army of uniformed British clerks", "dragging an army over these barren plains", etc) before about the 1980s. Most of the times that it appears in more formal publications (eg [here](https://www.cgdev.org/sites/default/files/1424271_file_Natsios_Counterbureaucracy.pdf)) it is cautiously labelled "attributed". No such letter appears to exist in the edited *Dispatches* of Wellington from the Peninsula.

Comment: Interestingly, the oldest I found were from the 1970s, and _all_  of them making the rounds in psychology/psychiatry circles, then to 'management', then to military (Colin Powell etc), with the letter itself making it 'back' to British government in 1994 https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/lords/1994/jul/26/defence It would make for an excellent answer if you could track this down to its real origins.

Comment: Adding to the likelihood of this being apocryphal, I think a general of the era would have had someone on staff to provide the figures purportedly requested. The quote "An army marches on its stomach" is attributed to Napoleon, after all.

Comment: The [Dispatches of Field Marshal the Duke of Wellington](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=The+Dispatches+of+Field+Marshal+the+Duke+of+Wellington) runs to 12 volumes, Volume IX contains the particular date in question. He sent several letters on the 11th August 1812 (pgs. 348-350) from _Torre Lodones, near Madrid_. These were  individually to Commodore Sir Home Popham, His Excellency Charles Stuart, Colonel Torrens & Earl Bathurst. Unsurprisingly, there wasn't one to the Foreign Office and none of the dispatches contained anything like the content mentioned above.

Comment: Earl Bathurst was the serving "Secretary of State for War and the Colonies" and it was to the holder of this post that Wellington's formal correspondence (to the Government) was usually addressed. So if Wellington did send a 'rebuke', it would most likely be to the Secretary of State and not to an entire department (outside of his chain of command).

Comment: @SteveBird thanks, well spotted! I thought the despatches would be able to confirm it's fictional, but for some reason had assumed they'd be a modern edition and so not available online. Google Books to the rescue as always...